# Ubuntu install error message

Tags: system-installation

I am currently running Windows 10 and would like to install Ubuntu as it is much more convenient than Windows for coding Ruby On Rails.

Though I am not sure how to do it properly.

My setup:

- One 256GB SSD with Windows boot on it
- One 3 TB HD where I store files (music ...) and also some large Windows install (Steam and games mostly)

I thought I could dedicate a partition on the 3TB HD drive to Ubuntu so I created a partition of 500 GB on this drive.

**Now Ubuntu install**

I wanted to install on the 500GB partition so i selected 
" something else"

Then highlighted my 500 GB partition. but got error : "No root file system is defined"

then I went back to install location menu and selected " install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" and it offers to create the install on the 256 GB SSD drive and call it "Ubuntu /dev/sdb6 (ext4)"

**So my question** : is it necessary to install it on the SSD drive ? There is only 100GB free on this drive and the proposed Ubuntu partition is 61 GB. I am not sure there will be enough left for swap..

Is it not possible to use the 500 GB partition even if it's not fast access ? (I have 32 GO ram so it may be only slightly low at start)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be installed to the HDD. Instead of creating a partition, leave it unallocated since ubuntu will need to make 2 partitions (swap and root). Then, choose the option to use freespace.
 You could also choose the something else option and make the partitions from the installer if you want to manually partition.

Note: you need Basic partitioning. Ubuntu does not know what to do with Windows dynamic partitions.

Comment: Ok I have erased my 500 gb partition and replaced it by free space in win 10. Now I choose "something else" and I see 500GB free space. As device for boot loader installation I leave with my 3TB drive but it still says No root file system is defined

Comment: sounds like the the disk is partitioned with Windows Dynamic partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use your second drive, ensure that you either resize the partition leaving it as "unallocated free space".

Then get something like Rufus [USB bootable Tool](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Install the Ubuntu Distro, and ensure you select the correct drive.

Personally, when you select the free space, I would recommend you use "Guided LVM" rather than root and swap. After the install, it should add the necessary boot loader and you're good to go!

Comment: This is what I have done: deleted my partition for 500GB free space. Though in 'solething else'   it still says no root file system... Should I pick 'instalk Ubuntu alongside windows ..' ?

Comment: I would.. as I think anything else would replace Windows 10 yes? ;-)

Comment: At the point where you chose "WHERE" to ensure, you should have two physical drives, your SSD, and you SATA HDD.

Comment: ok. It has installed properly on the 500GB free space. I think when I chose 'something else' I have setup the free space as ext4. And thn the install alongside picked that space. All good. And when I start my PC. I go to GRUB or something like that where I can choose to boot on ubuntu or revert to windows. So all good

Comment: One problem: one screen is not antialiased but I guess i needd to learn Ubuntu and tweak a bit

Comment: Once you boot up (EFI BIOS?), the bootloader should come up. Offering you Windows 10 or Ubuntu.

Antialiasing? I'm not all that sure why you think the OS cares about that? Is due to a hardware probe issue?

Is this a second screen you want to use? If you have a dedicated GPU (Nvidia or ATI), both support Linux.